# How to append and color bytes with byte viewer in c#

Tags: c#, binaryfiles

I'm trying to read big (~20+ MB) binary files, show their content to the user via the byte viewer and create a second binary file, that's based on the first one but has some bytes changed. The content of the second binary file should also be presented to the user and the differences to the first file should be highlighted (e.g. different color). I already developed code that does this, but it is using rich text boxes, which isn't very nice to view the bytes/hex chars. So I wanted to exchange the rich text boxes with the byte viewer. Since I read the first and write the second binary file step by step, I would have to append data to the byte viewer. So far I only found the methods to set a byte array or the content of a file to display in the viewer. Is there a possibility to append data? And my other question is: is it possible to highlight certain bytes of the byte viewer?
If the byte viewer doesn't offer these functionalities, what other options do I have to display the data as mentioned in a better way than the rich text boxes do?

Comment: Please show some code, what have you tried so far and what you expect to get

Comment: @FelixAv As I said before, I don't know the correct methods to append data to the byte viewer and to highlight certain bytes, so there's not much code concerning my problem.
Currently I use the SetBytes method, but it only sets the current byte array to display and these byte arrays are only a part of the whole data I want to show. So I would need to append them.

`using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
{
 using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
        {
  byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes(1000000);
  bv.SetBytes(bytes); //bv is the byte viewer
  ...
 }
}`